# How to hide API calls in website?

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services, laravel

I have developed a website with my friend. For the front-end we are using AngularJS, and for the backend we're using Laravel.

Whenever data has to be fetched, an API call is made from front-end to PHP.

My concern is that this API call is clearly visible in network panel. Then some bad guy can easily abuse this API. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases exposing your API is not bad thing, but you need to think about this:
1. You should design your API, so only legitimate operations can be made. In example: person shouldn't be able to delete whole database using API.
2. You could provide some authentication mechanism if needed, so the person trying to call your API will have to be logged in (authentication token should be stored in session and verified in server-side with every API call).

Comment: Yeah , these things are being handled by us .. proper authentication mechanism .. Any other suggestion ...

Comment: @voila Try this package https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token (mind you, there seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token/issues/44) with Laravel 4.2.9, but anything below should work).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide POST/GET Params form console. Try to make `JSONP` call in angular . JSONP calls are not real ajax requests and won't be shown in Firebug. You can also clear the console using `clearconsole()` after you receive the response and you can also authenticate the requesting IP in your laravel backend.

Answer (score 1):

It's just like regular routing. For example: Everybody knows that they can access a user's profile on Facebook on the `/:username` route, but Facebook prevents unauthorized clients from viewing that data. The same concept is used for REST routes.

Just like regular page requests, AJAX calls and the data passed / received can be seen by the user. JSONP can be used to prevent the API requests from being logged by regular developer tools, but that is not a good security solution your API can still be discerned by a malicious user.

Even if you encrypt the request payload and the response, it can be intercepted by a malicious user before encryption and after decryption.

You mentioned using proper authentication on your API, which is usually good enough for most cases.